# How to change Activity with event click ImageView?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am currently doing an android app which has 2 activities, say Activity A and Activity B. In Activity A, I have an `ImageView`.

Now, I want to change from Activity A to Activity B by clicking into `ImageView`. I try to do this, but all of them are false. How can I do that?

Comment: `setOnClickListener` is defined in `View`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this two method

**Method1:**

Use like this code:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MyFirstActivity.this, MySecondActivity.class));
            } 
});
```

**Method2:**

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

And implements in your class like this

```
  Class MyFirstActivity implements View.onClickListener {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     //... insert you imageview
  }


        @Override
       private void onClick(View v) {
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply set `clickListener` on the `imageView`

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // start activity code...
                startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
            } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
And in onClick function 
Write 
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SybActivity.class);
StartActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straight forward documentation detailing how how to start another activity using click events.

[Page on Android developer portal](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Please try looking up documentation before asking.

Answer (score 0):

If the id of the Imageview in Activity A is "imageView".

Intent class is used to set the current activity and next activity.

Intent takes the 1st parameter as the current activity and takes the 2nd parameter as the next activity.

method startActivity starts the activity which takes the parameter of the intent object.

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // start activity code...
                startActivity(new Intent(ActivityA.this,ActivityB.class));
            } 
    });
```